# Jenkins branch specifier can't be set to subfolder

Tags: angular, git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a project repository in Bitbucket in which I have `master` branch and `dev` branch.

I want to build and deploy to FTP server. `Dev` branch consists of two folders, where one is `backend` - laravel, the other is `frontend` - angular.

Now in Jenkins, I have set `Branch specifier` to: `*/dev/frontend/.*`

But this path does not work because when I start build, it fails:

```
... 
+ npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/package.json'
npm WARN Project No description
npm WARN Project No repository field.
npm WARN Project No README data
npm WARN Project No license field.
... and the rest ...
```

My build shell commands are:

```
npm install
npm run ng -- build --prod
```

Is there some plugin or some other way to get into the frontend folder so it can read the files required for build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branch specifier is not what you need. It is there to specify which branches you want to build using jenkins. You should set it back to default value, otherwise, jenkins may not build all branches.

What you need is to execute npm install in the frontend directory (e.g. with declarative pipeline)

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('build frontend') {
            steps {
                dir('frontend') {
                    sh 'npm install'
                    sh 'npm run ng -- build --prod'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I need to have branch specifier set to `*/dev` and the commands you wrote should be where? Its my first time with Jenkins.

Comment: the code i wrote is for Jenkinsfile declarative pipeline. How did you setup your project?

if you only want to build the dev branch, yes. if you want to build all branches, keep it empty

Comment: okay, but I dont know where to enter the code you wrote, I have replaced my shell build commands with what you provided but it doesnt work.I dont use pipeline. It is as Build step - Execute shell.

Comment: ok, then delete my code again. You have to change the directory using shell commands. Try to set `cd frontend` as first line before the npm install command

Comment: Okay seems like it solved the answer to my question. Btw, is there a tutorial on how to setup simple angular CI CD pipeline? I have not found anything simple and pipelines seem to be better way of doing this.

Comment: Jenkins documentation is quite good: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

I edited by answer providing a complete jenkins pipeline for angular project. Just create a file named Jenkinsfile in the root of your git repository and create a Multibranch pipeline project in Jenkins UI